Potential of charge density at $k=0$ in Fourier space?
I have stumbled upon something strange in some numerical experiments in 1D electrostatics. I am pretty sure this phenomenon is well-known and has a proper way to dealing with it, but I am not sure how to look for it, so I would appreciate any hints in pointing me to the right direction.
Assume I have a (known) charge density $\rho$ as a function of the spatial coordinate $x$. To find the potential, I can solve the Poisson equation (setting all constants to unity for simplicity)
$$ \nabla^2 \phi = - \rho$$
One way of solving this equation is transforming it to Fourier space - if the Fourier transform of $\rho(x)$ is known, and the boundary conditions are not too bad, this should be OK. The equation I get is
$$ \tilde{\phi}(k) = -\frac{\tilde{\rho}(k)}{k^2} $$
Here is my issue: if I want to do this procedure numerically, this will involve a discrete Fourier transform algorithm, possibly uniformly centered around $x=0$. However, this way, I will get a point in Fourier space where the potential is infinity, namely, at $k=0$ - this is clear from the division I have to go. This means that the inverse Fourier transform on $\phi$ will also not work numerically, and I can not generate the potential this way.
Is there a way around this problem so I can still keep working in Fourier space?

There is a factor of $k^2$ in the 3d integration measure that will help you out with the inverse Fourier transform. Also, the $k=0$ part of $\tilde \rho(k)$ corresponds to a uniform charge density in all space, which presumably you don't have. I guess these comments may not be helpful numerically. You could also try $\frac{1}{k^2}\to\frac{1}{k^2-i\Gamma}$, where you could take $\Gamma \to 0$ after the inverse transform (or see what happens numerically for various Gamma that get smaller), or it could represent some kind of damping effect.

I am not too worried about the analytical behaviour, but since the charge density is coming from an electronic structure calculation, I really should get a numerical procedure to work.

Is the charge density provided in k space or in real space? If in k space, it there a non-zero entry for k=0?

The user manuals or publications from the developers of the electronic structure software may address the issue of k=0 and how to handle it

I assume that $\rho(k)$ should go faster to zero than $k^2$, or else $\phi(0)$ is indeed infinite as the formula implies.

If you are doing numerics, then you are probably using the discrete Fourier transform. Discretisation changes slightly the problem and it is easier to see what is happening. In a discrete setting, you would get something like for $n\in\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$:
$$
\frac1{a^2}(2\phi_n-\phi_{n+1}-\phi_{n-1}) = \rho_n
$$
so that in the continuum limit $a\to0$, you would get:
$$
-\phi'' = \rho_n
$$
From DFT, you get:
$$
\frac2{a^2}(1-\cos(k_na))\hat\phi_n = \hat\rho_n \\
k_n = \frac{2\pi}{aN}
$$
which you solve to get:
$$
\hat\phi_n = \frac{a^2}{2(1-\cos(k_na))}\hat\rho_n
$$
Note that at fixed $k_n=k$ and sending $a\to0$, you recover the continuum limit:
$$
\hat\phi = \frac1{k^2}\hat\rho
$$
You are still potentially dividing by $0$ for $n=0$. You should rather view this as a prescription on $\rho$. This imposes that:
$$
\hat \rho_0 = 0
$$
or back in real space:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\rho_n = 0
$$
You can now understand better the condition, space must be charge neutral overall for an electrostatic field to exist. This follows from Gauss law:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\rho_n = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac1{a^2}(2\phi_n-\phi_{n+1}-\phi_{n-1}) = 0
$$
by telescoping sum.
This restriction on possible $\rho$ leads to the overall indeterminacy of $\phi$ up to an additive constant (gauge freedom). Back in Fourier space, $\hat\phi_0$ is underdetermined (formally $0/0$). In finite dimension, this is a consequence of the rank nullity theorem: charge neutrality and gauge freedom are two sides of the same coin.
All these aspects have their analogues for continuous fields. Just replace sums and differences by integrals and derivatives.
